# How to add additional metric to Grafana dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana, openfaas

I am currently using "OpenFaas" dashboard in Grafana, but it doesn't have CPU metrics, how can I add it to my existing dashboard? I downloaded JSON file from https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/3434

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the dashboard and add the panels you want? The metrics itself must be available through a datasource like Prometheus or InfluxDB, of course.